# Is there a way of loading images better with OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to load images and use hough transformation to capture the black bounded area inside the paper and then perform a few counting operations inside the boxes. Naturally, this requires that I am able to load the images in relatively good quality.

Issue is when I am loading using openCV's cv2.imread() I get a very watered down version of the picture which I can't quickly process. To make it worse, I can't render the image using cv2.imshow(), my IDE hangs every time I try to see it. So I have to use matplotlib to render and see the image step by step.

I don't know any other packages for image processing (maybe pillow, but I don't know whether it will do what I need it to do).

My original image is this:
[image: original image]

```
img = cv2.imread("img1-min.jpg")
```

Because the cv2.imshow() method results in a window that crashes, I resorted to matplotlib:

```
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('my picture')
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

After that:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor (img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 75, 150)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50, 50, 5)

if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 5)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('my picture')
plt.show()
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see, very messy. My hunch is that this is because of the way the original image is loaded. Is there a way I can improve the loading process so that it makes it easier to apply the Hough Lines?

Comment: In all likelihood your image is loading fine, it's just that when you display it, you can't display all the pixels. Try displaying a region of the image small enough to fit on your monitor and see what you get.

Comment: Even after almost 2 decades of writing software professionally, my hunch is that the problem is my code, not a (extensively used) third party library. It's rather rare that's not the case. | You can confirm that `imread` works fine by simply `imwrite`ing the image back to another file. It would be a good idea to save the result to file anyway and use a proper image view to display and inspect it, given how large the input is. Plotting it at less than 10% scale as you have here won't allow you to see anything relevant.

Comment: Actually, seems to me that your call to `cv2.HoughLinesP` is incorrect -- the fifth parameter is `lines`, so the main problem is that you're actually telling it to look for lines at least 5 pixels long... when the image has ~2500 pixels across. That ends up finding all sorts of garbage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the image is loading fine with `cv2.imread()` but its so large with a dimension of `2976x3838`, your IDE has trouble displaying the image. I believe you're applying `cv2.HoughLinesP()` incorrectly. Instead of using `cv2.HoughLinesP()`, here's an alternative approach to detect the lines

---

The idea is to threshold then find the bounding box of the board to create a mask. From this mask, we perform a perspective transform to obtain a top down image. This will allow us to detect lines better

[image]
[image]

Once we have the detected board, we can extract the ROI

[image]

Then we simply detect vertical and horizontal lines

[image]
[image]

Result

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def perspective_transform(image, corners):
    def order_corner_points(corners):
        # Separate corners into individual points
        # Index 0 - top-right
        #       1 - top-left
        #       2 - bottom-left
        #       3 - bottom-right
        corners = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners]
        top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r = corners[0], corners[1], corners[2], corners[3]
        return (top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l)

    # Order points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_corner_points(corners)
    top_l, top_r, bottom_r, bottom_l = ordered_corners

    # Determine width of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((bottom_r[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((bottom_r[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - top_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - top_l[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # Determine height of new image which is the max distance between 
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((top_r[0] - bottom_r[0]) ** 2) + ((top_r[1] - bottom_r[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((top_l[0] - bottom_l[0]) ** 2) + ((top_l[1] - bottom_l[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # Construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in 
    # top_r, top_l, bottom_l, bottom_r order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1], 
                    [0, height - 1]], dtype = "float32")

    # Convert to Numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # Find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # Return the transformed image
    return cv2.warpPerspective(image, matrix, (width, height))

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
original = image.copy()
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.015 * peri, True)

    if area > 150000 and len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.drawContours(image,[c], 0, (36,255,12), 3)
        cv2.drawContours(mask,[c], 0, (255,255,255), -1)
        transformed = perspective_transform(original, approx)

mask = cv2.bitwise_and(mask, original)

# Remove horizontal lines
gray = cv2.cvtColor(transformed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
board_thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (55,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(board_thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(transformed, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 9)
    pass

# Remove vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,55))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(board_thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(transformed, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 9)

cv2.imwrite('thresh.png', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('image.png', image)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('transformed.png', transformed)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: @nathancy you are a genius. Script works like a charm. However, if I use it in its current form with [this image](https://imgur.com/a/ecLMAyo), the output is turned 90 degrees to the right [here](https://imgur.com/a/somjd0h). Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @Sam, the reason why is it turned 90 degrees is due to the clockwise order the four corner points are obtained. You could simply use `cv2.rotate()` or [`imutils.rotate()`](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils#rotation) to get the correct orientation